# How to save current machine state before updating in Win 10?

Tags: windows-10

I there is an option called "hybernate", but Win 10 is forcing me to update. I opened a bunch of apps and is reading several PDFs, is there a way to save the computer's state "manually"? Thank in advance.

Comment: You could use something like Norton Ghost to image the machines current state, or a similar tool; assuming I understood your question.

Comment: *Any* tool that makes a full disk image, e.g., free Macrium Reflect, will save an exact image of the drive at the time the app is run.